# Browser redirected outside Facebook instead of redirecting it inside iframe

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, iframe

I’ve just created a Facebook app, this is my first attempt and I followed Facebook developer's documentation totally, while completing everything as stated I am stucked at this strange situation:

1. During authentication my app, the app redirects my browser outside
   the Facebook to the website page where my website is hosted, instead
   of redirecting it inside iframe. Am unable to redirect to some other page in my app direct plus also cant use app namespace page
2. I am unable to retrieve the user_id from signed request parameter

*code for landhere.php*

```
<?php
    include ('src/facebook.php');
    $app_id = "*******";
    $app_secret = "*********";
    $redirect_uri = "http://myweb.com/myapp/landhere.php";
    //$redirect_uri = "http://appplatform.info/WFBRU/start.php";
    //$redirect_uri = "http://apps.facebook.com/wfbrumapp";

    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

    $id = $data["user_id"];
    $authorized_code = $_GET["code"];
    $oauth_token = $data["oauth_token"];
    $like_status = $data["page"]["liked"];
    echo "<br>page id = $id";
    echo "<br>page admin = $authorized_code";
    echo "<br>like status = $like_status";
    echo "<br>country = $oauth_token";

    if (empty($authorized_code)) {
        echo "string";
        $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
        $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri . "&state=" . $_SESSION['state'];
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
        //echo("<script> window.top.location='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    } else {
        $authenticate_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $authorized_code . "";
        $response = @file_get_contents($authenticate_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);
        $access_token = $params['access_token'];

        $userId = $_POST["user_id"];
        echo $userId;
        if ($like_status) {
            echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"start.php\" id=\"landingForm\">";
            echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"user_id\" value=" . $id . " style=\"display: none\">";
            echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"oauth_token\" value=" . $oauth_token . " style=\"display: none\">";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "<script>document.forms['landingForm'].submit()</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class=\"likepage\">";
            echo("<b class=\"welcome\"></b><br/>");
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

---

*stuck in infinite loop:*

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

    $id = $data["user_id"];
    $authorized_code = $_GET["code"];
    $oauth_token = $data["oauth_token"];
    $like_status = $data["page"]["liked"];
    echo "<br>page id = $id";
    echo "<br>page admin = $authorized_code";
    echo "<br>like status = $like_status";
    echo "<br>country = $oauth_token";
    if ($data["page"]["liked"]) {
        echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"start.php\" id=\"landhereForm\">";
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"user_id\" value=" . $id . " style=\"display: none\">";
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"oauth_token\" value=" . $oauth_token . " style=\"display: none\">";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<script>document.forms['landhereForm'].submit()</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class=\"likepage\">";
        echo("<b class=\"welcome\"></b><br/>");
        echo "</div>";
    }
} else if (!empty($_GET["error"])) {
    echo "user hasn't authorized your app";
}else if (!empty($_GET["code"])) {
    $authorized_code = $_GET["code"];
    $authenticate_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" .    $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $authorized_code . "";
    $response = @file_get_contents($authenticate_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
    //header('Location: http://apps.facebook.com/myapp');
    header('Location: http://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_***********');
} else {
    echo "string";
    echo "<br>page id = $id";
    echo "<br>page admin = $authorized_code";
    echo "<br>like status = $like_status";
    echo "<br>country = $oauth_token";
    $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri . "&state=" . $_SESSION['state'];
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    //echo("<script> window.top.location='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}
```

Comment: Never display your app secret like that, unless it's not the real one, in which case I take it back.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you got this wrong a big.

You should follow the [Authentication tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), it describes all the steps:

1. If the user is not authenticated you send him to the auth dialog via the js script as you wrote.
2. Facebook redirects back to your page, not in an iframe, it's a redirection on the main window.
3. In case the user declined the app you will have "error", "error_reason" and "error_description" in the GET data, remember you are not inside facebook at the time.
4. If the user granted your app, get redirected to your page (in the main window), you then should exchange the code with an active access token and then redirect the user to your fb app (*http(s)://apps.facebook.com/YOUR-APP-NAME*).
5. When facebook loads it will load your app inside an iframe, then you will get the signed request and you can show your canvas page.

Here's a modified version of your php code, some of it is pseudo since I'm not much of a php programmer.

```
<?php
    include ('src/facebook.php');
    $app_id = "******";
    $app_secret = "******";

    if (access_token in session) {
        $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
        list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
        $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

        $id = $data["user_id"];
        $oauth_token = $data["oauth_token"];
        $like_status = $data["page"]["liked"];
        echo "<br>page id = $id";
        echo "<br>like status = $like_status";
        echo "<br>country = $oauth_token";
    } else if (error in get_data) {
        // user hasn't authorized your app
    } else if (code in get_data) {
        $authorized_code = $_GET["code"];
        $authenticate_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $authorized_code . "";
        $response = @file_get_contents($authenticate_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);
        $access_token = $params['access_token'];
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
        header('Location: http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME');
    } else {
        $redirect_uri = "http://myweb.com/myapp/landhere.php";
        echo "string";
        $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
        $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri . "&state=" . $_SESSION['state'];
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    }
?>
```

It's not tested or anything, it's just to give you a nudge in the right direction.
Hope this helps.

---

## Edit

Modified version of your 2nd piece of code:

```
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST["signed_request"], 2);
$signed_request = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

$access_token = null;
if (!empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
} else if (!empty($signed_request['oauth_token'])) {
    $access_token = $signed_request['oauth_token'];
}

if ($access_token != null) {
    $id = $access_token["user_id"];
    $authorized_code = $_GET["code"];
    $oauth_token = $access_token["oauth_token"];
    $like_status = $access_token["page"]["liked"];
    echo "<br>page id = $id";
    echo "<br>page admin = $authorized_code";
    echo "<br>like status = $like_status";
    echo "<br>country = $oauth_token";
    if ($data["page"]["liked"]) {
        echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"start.php\" id=\"landhereForm\">";
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"user_id\" value=" . $id . " style=\"display: none\">";
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"oauth_token\" value=" . $access_token . " style=\"display: none\">";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<script>document.forms['landhereForm'].submit()</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class=\"likepage\">";
        echo("<b class=\"welcome\"></b><br/>");
        echo "</div>";
    }
} else if (!empty($_GET["error"])) {
    echo "user hasn't authorized your app";
}else if (!empty($_GET["code"])) {
    $authorized_code = $_GET["code"];
    $authenticate_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" .    $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $authorized_code . "";
    $response = @file_get_contents($authenticate_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
    //header('Location: http://apps.facebook.com/myapp');
    header('Location: http://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_***********');
} else {
    echo "string";
    echo "<br>page id = $id";
    echo "<br>page admin = $authorized_code";
    echo "<br>like status = $like_status";
    echo "<br>country = $oauth_token";
    $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri . "&state=" . $_SESSION['state'];
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    //echo("<script> window.top.location='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}
```

Comment: thankyou for such a detailed reply help alot, Ive updated my code above in my question according to ur suggestions but now the code is stuck in an infinite loop probably its running  `echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");'`again and again.. what should i do now? kindly help.

Comment: I believe that it's because you already authorized your application, and you're getting the signed request, don't parse it (since you've never set up the access token in session) and go straight to the js redirect. The edit in my answer should overcome that, it checks if the signed request has the access token or the session does.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) $redirect_uri should point to your facebook app, not your website

2) in javascript, you should check to see if "apps.facebook.com" is in the top frame's url, if not then do a redirect

```
if(top.location.href.indexOf("apps.facebook.com") > 0){
    top.location.href = YOUR_FACEBOOK_CANVAS_APP_URL;
}
```